# How to show the cluster assignment in each cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Is there a way to show the the member in a cluster after cutree step in R?
for example:

```
tree <- hclust(dist, method='single')
plot(tree, hang=-1, cex=0.8)
cutree(tree, h=18)
```

I obtain sth like:

```
X10100  X3755 X13068   X264 X13216 
 1      1      2      2      3 
X8379 X13727  X9925 X13849   X467 
 3      4      4      5      5 
X14265   X388 X14426  X8246 X14961 
 6      6      7      7      8 
X17037  X1200   X844 X13024   X155 
 8      9      9     10     11
```

I want to see/print it as a more straightforward way 
such as:

```
 cluster 1: 10100,03755
    cluster 2: ..........
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the results using `split` or `by` :

```
 hh <- cutree(tree, h=18)
 split(names(hh),hh)
```

Or

```
 by(names(hh),hh,paste,collapse=',')
```